# Best way to query or search through a CSV from HTML website

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I am wondering what the best way would be to search or query through a csv that will be in the same directory as an HTML site I am writing. There is a search bar where a user can put the name of someone into, when they click search I'd like there to be an Alert popping up showing some information from that csv matching the name they entered.

I've looked for a few examples in Javascript and php. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around them tho. Does anyone have a fairly simple script that would accomplish what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: use javascript for interface, use ajax for querys and at laste can use javascript or php for read csv

Comment: here read csv with javascript https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow:+read+csv+from+javascript

Comment: here read csv from php https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow:+read+csv+from+php

Comment: keep in mind, it really depends on your csv layout.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. Most obvious ones are:

1- In JS, you can use built-in CSV parsing function in D3JS:

http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346

2- In JS, you can use built-in jQuery.get() or jQuery.ajax() function in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

3- In JS, you can use $http service in Angular:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

4- In Php, you can use fgetcsv() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

5- In Php/JS, you can convert your file to JSON and upload it to Backend as a service platform such as Firebase and query it from your app via API calls.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Answer (score 1):

If having the whole csv on the client side is not an issue, then on page load, I would [read the csv through PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and keep the data in a javascript variable so it essentially becomes a client side search (super fast search).

If you should not have the csv data on the client side, then write a webservice in PHP to read the csv (or, pre read using some other script and store the full csv as an array using [php memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) which is in memory store) and then your web service can just search the in-memory array which will also be a little fast than reading the full csv every time your search.